# SVG <text /> is getting cut off

Tags: svg, svg-filters

See fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dgt26upk/

The text is NOT being cut off by the `<svg />` element.  It seems to be an arbitrary cut of based on the actual `<text />` element.

Is there a way to fix this, perhaps using filters(clip mask) and using a `<rect />` rather than a `<text />` element?  Or is there an easier way?

Comment: I see nothing at all in Firefox which is the correct rendering for an feMorphology element with a radius of 0

Comment: k try that https://jsfiddle.net/dgt26upk/1/ .  The 0 is not the problem.  the problem is a very high number for radius, but I figured it out.

Comment: Actually firefox wasn't animating, I guess it handles `ids` differently.  Try this for the example of it breaking https://jsfiddle.net/dgt26upk/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `<filter />` allows you to specify `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`.

So, if I want a huge dilation, I have to make sure to use a negative x, y, and a large width, height.

https://jsfiddle.net/dgt26upk/5/